# using touch() to update timestamp of custom timestamp field in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4, orm, eloquent

Is there a way to use `touch()` for updating timestamp of `is_online` field in table instead of updating `created_at` field in **laravel** `Eloquent ORM`

At present I am using

```
User::where('id',$senderId )->update(array('is_online' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')));
```

Answer (score 9):

No, the touch method isn't written for updating anything other than the built in timestamps, but you could write your own function in your User Model, if you want to. Something like this

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    public function touchOnline()
    {
        $this->is_online = $this->freshTimestamp();
        return $this->save();
    }
}
```

and then do replace your old code with

```
User::find($senderId)->touchOnline();
```

A few more lines of code, but maybe a slight bit more readable.

You can [find the code behind the touch function here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1677), if you're curious.

Comment: No, if anything I'd guess probably slower. But then again touch is probably also slower than updating the created_at or updated_at manually in the same way you're doing.

Comment: But the main reason we're using Laravel isn't speed (there are far speedier frameworks) - it's probably readability and ease of use. And in that respect I think my proposition is better.
But if you're doing the update really often I understand if you want to go the more raw way :)

Answer (score 3):

**Laravel 4.2**

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface
{
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        /*
        static::creating(function($table) {
            $table->foo = 'Bar';
        });
        */
        static::updating(function($table) {
            $table->is_online = $this->freshTimestamp();
            // $table->something_else = 'The thing';
        });
    }
}
```

**Usage**. Just call the native touch method.

```
User::find($senderId)->touch();
```

Comment: You should be aware the `touch()` call will also update the `updated_at` column.
And, more importantly, the `updating` event listener introduced will also refresh the `is_online` anytime the model is updated for some reason.
When it's triggered by the user editing her details that's probably fine, but if the update is because the admin is editing the a user it is probably undesired behavior.

Comment: @Arvid Well noted! Maybe we can do some verification before call `User::find($senderId)->touch();`, for example not execute when the admin is editing or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

A quick alternative is to override the CREATED_AT constant in your model like

```
Class User extends Model
{
    protected UPDATED_AT = 'is_online';
}
$user->touch();
```

Just continue touching