# Custom "touches" functionality for Laravel model

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a has many relationship in my database and in the child model I have the `touches` array defined like so

```
 protected $touches = ['parent'];
```

I am looking to do something similar to what is described in these two questions:

- [using touch() to update timestamp of custom timestamp field in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27597465/using-touch-to-update-timestamp-of-custom-timestamp-field-in-laravel)
- [Custom Timestamps in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29207211/custom-timestamps-in-laravel)

But with a slight difference, I want the a boolean column on my parent model to be updated when a change occurs in the child model. This works for touches, but I can't figure out how to do it with a custom property instead.

I have tried this in my parent model with no avail:

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::updating(function ($table) {
        $table->is_finished = true;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this thread](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/6325) it appears that the `updating()` event only fires in the event that the model was "dirty," i.e. had fields that had changed value, and therefore needed to be updated. So, if no data on the parent model had changed, it could be that your code never gets executed. My guess is that even though the timestamp on the parent is touched, it is exempted from the list of properties that can be considered dirty.

You might instead just add this code to the child model:

```
// this is whatever property points to the parent model
public function parent() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Parent');
}

// this overrides the update() method in the Eloquent\Model class
public function update($attributes = Array, $options = Array) {

    parent::update($attributes, $options);

    $this->parent->is_finished = true;
    $this->parent->save();
}
```

Haven't tested this, but don't see why it shouldn't work.